# Unsupported format character in raw f-string

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute the following query using sqlalchemy.

```py
engine=sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3306/cst')

cst_delete_query = rf"""delete from customer where STATUS like '%CT%'"""

with engine.connect().execution_options(autocommit=True) as conn:
     conn.execute(cst_delete_query)
```

This results in the following error:

```py
ValueError: unsupported format character 'C' (0x43) at index 41
```

Comment: Why are you using a raw f-string in the first place? It doesn't look like you need either part of that functionality, the raw string non-backslash-parsing or the f-string interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent character is a string operator and should be escaped to be used in a string. You can escape it with a second `%`.

```py
cst_delete_query = rf"DELETE FROM customer WHERE status LIKE '%%CT%%'"
```